# Nesting C-Macros, CRC calculation, Eclipse Java crash

Tags: c, eclipse, c-preprocessor, crc

What I have done is awfully heavy on the preprocessor.  MinGW takes a minute or 2 to compile it, but it does pass unit tests; Eclipse is struggling and pops up a Java heap low, or eventually overflow.  My question is there a way to make this easier for the preprocessor?  Shall I just increase my Java heap?  Or is there a better way to populate a table at compile time

Here it is:

I have created a CRC look up table and decided to populate it at compile time (key word: compile time), and didn't want to hard code any numbers.  So I came up with a macro to calculate CRC, only hard coding the polynomial. (perhaps slightly hard to read, but it passes unit tests)

```
 // Define CRC polynomial
 #define POLYNOMIAL (0x8005)
 #define CRC_1ITERATION(crc) ( \
              (((crc)&0x7FFF)<<1)^( ((crc)&0x8000)?POLYNOMIAL:0 )  )
```

And then propagated it to 16 iterations... a re-invocation of the macro 16 iterations deep!

```
 // Iterate the CRC polynomial
 #define CRC_2ITERATIONS(crc)  CRC_1ITERATION(  CRC_1ITERATION(crc) )
 #define CRC_4ITERATIONS(crc)  CRC_2ITERATIONS( CRC_2ITERATIONS(crc))
 #define CRC_8ITERATIONS(crc)  CRC_4ITERATIONS( CRC_4ITERATIONS(crc))
 #define CRC_16ITERATIONS(crc) CRC_8ITERATIONS( CRC_8ITERATIONS(crc))
```

`CRC_16ITERATIONS()` is now something I can invoke to transition an input CRC to it's output 16 iterations later.  I use this to populated my table.  Actually, I made even more nested macros to populate the table, but to keep things simple this code is enough to make Eclipse struggle:

```
// Populate the table (EDIT: corrected spelling)
CRC_16ITERATIONS(0), CRC_16ITERATIONS(1), CRC_16ITERATIONS(2), CRC_16ITERATIONS(3),
CRC_16ITERATIONS(4), CRC_16ITERATIONS(5), CRC_16ITERATIONS(6), CRC_16ITERATIONS(7),
CRC_16ITERATIONS(8), CRC_16ITERATIONS(9), CRC_16ITERATIONS(10), CRC_16ITERATIONS(11),
CRC_16ITERATIONS(12), CRC_16ITERATIONS(13), CRC_16ITERATIONS(14), CRC_16ITERATIONS(15)
```

It worked in MinGW including passing unit tests but like I said, I think I'm blowing some sort of parenthesis or macro expansion stack in Java/Eclipse.  I was hoping to scale this up to a 256 entry table but I suspect MinGW will take a half-hour to compile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first eight iterations just shift the byte up eight places.  You can do that in the argument, and use `CRC_8ITERATIONS` instead of `CRC_16ITERATIONS` (which by the way you misspelled it `CRC_16ITERATION` several times).

I.e.:

```
CRC_8ITERATIONS(0), CRC_8ITERATIONS(1 << 8), CRC_8ITERATIONS(2 << 8), CRC_8ITERATIONS(3 << 8),
CRC_8ITERATIONS(4 << 8), CRC_8ITERATIONS(5 << 8), CRC_8ITERATIONS(6 << 8), CRC_8ITERATIONS(7 << 8),
CRC_8ITERATIONS(8 << 8), CRC_8ITERATIONS(9 << 8), CRC_8ITERATIONS(10 << 8), CRC_8ITERATIONS(11 << 8),
CRC_8ITERATIONS(12 << 8), CRC_8ITERATIONS(13 << 8), CRC_8ITERATIONS(14 << 8), CRC_8ITERATIONS(15 << 8)
```

That compiles about 256 times faster for me than using `CRC_16ITERATIONS`.

For just that particular set, I can go faster still by initially shifting up those four zeros at the top, and using `CRC_4ITERATIONS`.  I.e.:

```
CRC_4ITERATIONS(0), CRC_4ITERATIONS(1 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(2 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(3 << 12),
CRC_4ITERATIONS(4 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(5 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(6 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(7 << 12),
CRC_4ITERATIONS(8 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(9 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(10 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(11 << 12),
CRC_4ITERATIONS(12 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(13 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(14 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(15 << 12)
```

That compile time was too fast for me to measure.

I can take it further, add a `CRC_3ITERATIONS`, and do this:

```
0, CRC_1ITERATION(1 << 15), CRC_2ITERATIONS(2 << 14), CRC_2ITERATIONS(3 << 14),
CRC_3ITERATIONS(4 << 13), CRC_3ITERATIONS(5 << 13), CRC_3ITERATIONS(6 << 13), CRC_3ITERATIONS(7 << 13),
CRC_4ITERATIONS(8 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(9 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(10 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(11 << 12),
CRC_4ITERATIONS(12 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(13 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(14 << 12), CRC_4ITERATIONS(15 << 12)
```

You could use this trick on the first 128 bytes to only iterate as many times as needed with `CRC_7ITERATIONS`, `CRC_6ITERATIONS`, etc.  The last 128 bytes will all need to use `CRC_8ITERATIONS`, which is still pretty fast.  At least for me using clang llvm 3.5.

Though I prefer just running a separate program to generate a file to include that has the table in it.

Comment: That's awesome.  I totally should have seen that.  Yup, I can now do a table with 256 entries no problem.  I'll correct the spellings in the questions, I kept re-factoring and re-pasting and obviously missed the plural I added.  Thanks!